# image getting saved in simulator gallery but not in iphone gallery

Tags: iphone, ios

Trying to save the image in iphone gallery with following code below, but working fine in simulator, not in iphone.

```
-(void)saveTkt
{
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
[data writeToFile:@"f.png" atomically:YES];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), nil);
}
```

edited code

```
-(void)saveTkt
{
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
[data writeToFile:@"f.png" atomically:YES];

ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    //show alert for asking the user to give permission

}

//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), nil);

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[img CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[img imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
        // TODO: error handling
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        // TODO: success handling
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Saved suceesfully in photos album." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];

ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock assetGroupEnumerator =
^(ALAssetsGroup *assetGroup, BOOL *stop) {
    if (assetGroup != nil) {
        // do somthing
    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock assetFailureBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error enumerating photos: %@",[error description]);

};

NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAll;

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator failureBlock:assetFailureBlock];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Framework assetsLibrary

```
 ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
if (error) {
// TODO: error handling
} else {
// TODO: success handling
}
}];
[library release];
```

Comment: #import <AssetsLibrary/ALAssetsLibrary.h>

Comment: ma having 3gs with ios6 not working there but iphon5 working.

Comment: is there permission issue in device

Comment: check status:

ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

Comment: actual thing is i am taking screen shot and saving that

Comment: How can the user give permission to access iphone gallery, by device or programmatically by me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766535/request-access-to-photo-library-during-app-launch

Comment: delete app from device and after check.. because of one u not allow to access photo then it will never ask you to permission

Comment: did already gaurav doing from testflight done atleast three times sent new build removed old first but same.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation say that the completion handler must conform to this:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)

```
- (void) image: (UIImage *) image didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo;
```

And there's an error parameter passed along, which you should print out to see what the actual true error is.

For example:

```
- (void) image: (UIImage *) image didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo
{
    if(error != NULL)
    {
        NSLog( @"error while saving image is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not going in this method, means no such error. but not saving in iphone gallery.

Comment: did you also change this selector to match in your call to "`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with NSData first if you need It, or you can simply do that without NSData

```
NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(file,1);
UIImageView *img;
img.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dataImage];
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum( [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dataImage], nil, nil, nil);
```

Hope ,it will work